# Java: BASE64Decoder outputs wrong value

Tags: java, base64

I have a problem with decoding text.

I have a field in my app:

```
JTextArea jCertImport = new JTextArea();
```

jCertImport contains BASE64 encoded text.
I want to decode text inserted in jCertImport, so I can get the byte form before encoding:

```
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

...

byte [] cert_bin = null;
BASE64Decoder cert_decoded = new BASE64Decoder();
try {
cert_bin = cert_decoded.decodeBuffer(jCertImport.getText());
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

and after that I get the the byte form of my cert, but the value is different than the one before encoding. Why? I thought, that when I use encode on some value and then decode on the output I should get the oryginal value before encoding.

Comment: How are you encoding the base64 text? The decoding seems fine to me.

Comment: There are base64 encoders/decoders online where you can paste in text to see what you get.  Try your text in one of those.

Comment: BASE64Encoder key_base = new BASE64Encoder();
key_base.encode(key); // key_base is then decoded the same way as above and the value is different

Comment: Online encoders/decoders output correct value, but that doesn't help me.

Comment: What is the value in text area and what is the output you get? What is the original text and how is it encoded?

Comment: While this *should* work, I wouldn't recommend using classes in the sun.misc package, as they are not intended for public consumption. Here is an example of how to use the Base64Encoder from the Apache Commons library: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/02/how-to-encode-decode-string-in-java.html